# Redux performance questions in react native

Tags: react-native, redux

Suppose I'm writing a Twitter clone but much simpler. A tweet looks like this:
[image]

With a `Like` button as circled in the picture. Every tweet has states like this:

```
{
    tweetId: '123456789',
    message: 'Stack Overflow',
    date: 125878315832,
    user: {
        uid: '431827512',
        username: 'some_user_name',
        displayName: 'some_display_name',
        profilePictureUrl: 'https://some-url.com'
    },
    liked: false
}
```

Where `liked` indicates whether the viewer has liked this tweet. If `liked` is false, then the `Like` button will stay uncolored, if it's true, then the button will become red. I store all tweets in `redux store` in a structure like this:

```
{
    [tweetId]: {
        message: 'Stack Overflow',
        date: 125878315832,
        user: {
            uid: '431827512',
            username: 'some_user_name',
            displayName: 'some_display_name',
            profilePictureUrl: 'https://some-url.com'
        },
        liked: false
    },
    [tweetId]: {
        ...
        ...
    },
    ...
    ...
}
```

And this is my reducer `tweet_reducer.js` and how I handle `LIKE_TWEET` action in it, the `LIKE_TWEET` action returns the `tweetId` of the tweet that's being liked:

```
export default function (state = { tweets: {} }, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        ...    // Other cases
        case LIKE_TWEET:
            const tweetId = action.payload;
            const tweet = state.tweets[tweetId];
            return {
                tweets: {
                    ...state.tweets,
                    [tweetId]: {
                        ...tweet,
                        liked: true
                    }
                }
            };
    }
}
```

This way, I update the `liked` field of that particular tweet in store. And in my component, I have `componentWillReceiveProps` that handles receiving updated tweets. Therefore, now, the `Like` button of that particular tweet should be red. This all happens as expected, except that it takes about 1 second for the `like` button to turn red when `store` has more than 50 tweets in it. How can I make it faster? BTW, each tweet is a `PureComponent` not a `Component`

Comment: Do you have redux logging middleware running? If so, everything is much slower when it's enabled.

Comment: @fubar I have actually never heard of `redux logging middleware`, so my guess is I'm not using it. I have like 9 reducers in my app, which I don't think is a lot, every time I need to update a global state, for example, the color theme of the app, everything is just so slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some simple time-stamped logging to your code to find out where the time is going - when you enter/exit each of your reducers, when you publish your actions, and when your component is notified of the appState change, and when you change the color of the button.  This will tell you which calls are quick (as expected) and which are not.  Then you'll know where to look for your missing second...